# Numpy to return average of 3D matrix

Tags: python, numpy

I have a 3D Numpy matrix named `stocks` that has shape `(A, P, T)`, with `A` corresponding to the number of stock symbols, `P` corresponding to number of prices for the stock at a given point in time, and `T` corresponding to the time.

```
stocks = np.array([ [ [1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9] ], [ [10,11,12],[13,14,15],[16,17,18] ], [ [19,20,21],[22,23,24],[25,26,27] ], [ [28,29,30],[31,32,33],[34,35,36] ] ])
```

I would like to return a 2D Numpy matrix of shape `(P, T)` where each element is the ***average*** of the stock price at a given time.

How would I do this?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: What have you tried?  This is one line of code.  `out = numpy.mean( array, axis=0 )`

Comment: I've tried `np.mean`, but I'm not familiar with applying that to 3D matrices.  In your example, `array` is just the name of the 3D matrix?

Comment: "I've tried `np.mean`, but I'm not familiar", have you read the documentation then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import numpy as np

# shape (A, P, T)
stocks = np.array([ [ [1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9] ], [ [10,11,12],[13,14,15],[16,17,18] ], [ [19,20,21],[22,23,24],[25,26,27] ], [ [28,29,30],[31,32,33],[34,35,36] ] ])

# this will give you the mean calculated along the first dimension
# the shape will be (P, T)
out_0 = np.mean(stocks, axis=0)

# this will be of the shape (A, T)
out_1 = np.mean(stocks, axis=1)

# this will be of the shape (A, P)
out_2 = np.mean(stocks, axis=2)
```